# Grad School Interviews with Multiple Programs at same School

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, interview

I️ applied to 3 programs within the same school (2 of which are joint with another institution). All of the programs are related to my research interests, and the main professors I️ would want to work with are affiliated with all 3 programs.

I️ ended up getting interviews at all 3 programs which brings me to my question - for the interviews I️ have to provide a ranked list of the faculty I️ want to interview with. Would it be strange to interview with the same faculty multiple times? For example, a specific PI (that is the PI I most want to work with), actually encouraged me to also apply to one of the programs after I️ talked to him and mentioned I️ was applying to the other two programs - I'm unsure whether I️ should interview with him at the interview sessions for each of the 3 programs (since I️ wrote about his work in my statement of purpose so it may be weird to the admissions committee if I️ didn't). It also seems weird, however, interviewing with the same person 3 times.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you would have repeat interviews with the same person unless it is a group interview (group of professors). If they know of your interest in the various positions they will ask whatever questions need to be asked when they meet you.

List the professors you want to work with and ignore the overlap. Let them work out the details.

Of course, someone may want to sit in on more than one interview if the positions are different enough. But they are likely pretty busy. I they come back for more, I'd take it as a sign of high interest.

Answer (score 0):

When I was a graduate student, current students helped prospective incoming students navigate campus and get to their various meetings with professors, etc.

It occurred a couple times during these visiting weekends that the program had scheduled meetings with students who already met professors they were scheduled to meet with, either because they had already interviewed with another program, or in a couple cases because they were already acquainted from previous research interactions (some even employees in their lab!). It was pretty much up to the combination of student and professor whether the meeting actually happened, and either way it was not a problem or "big deal".

I would mention the specific faculty you want to work with, even if the same person is listed once. However, I would also communicate to all these programs that you've been invited to interview elsewhere at the institution and also that a particular PI is a part of multiple programs. The people doing scheduling might not talk to each other very much, as the admissions committees and office staff are not likely to overlap, even if some of the faculty do! You may need/want to work out other details in your interviews, especially if they are in-person (they could be on three different weekends! are you going to travel to the same place all three times?).